# c++ no matching constructor when constructor is declared

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm trying to create a very basic text game in c++. My issue is with my State class which represents the current game state.

The .h file that declares the class:

```
#ifndef TEXTADV_STATE_H
#define TEXTADV_STATE_H

#include "Room.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

class State {
    Room *currentRoom;
    Room *previousRoom;
public:
    explicit State(Room *startRoom);
    static std::list<GameObject*> inventory;
    void goTo(Room *target);
    void goBack();
    void announceLoc() const;
    static void addObj(GameObject *obj);
    static void remObj(Gameobject *obj);
    Room* getCurrentRoom() const;
    Room* getPrevRoom() const;
};

#endif //TEXTADV_STATE_H
```

The definition of the constructor in the corresponding .cpp file:

```
State::State(Room *startRoom) : currentRoom(startRoom) {};
```

In main.cpp I have initialised a State object as:

```
State *currentState;
```

I get this error when assinging a value to currentState:
No matching constructor for initialization of 'State' candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided

```
void initState() {
    currentState = new State(Room::rooms.front());
}
```

Other questions/threads I have read seem to say that the error is to do with overloading the constructor, or not having a default constructor. These declarations used to work fine and I haven't changed them, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

For posterity here is some of my room class (.h file):

```
#ifndef TEXTADV_ROOM_H
#define TEXTADV_ROOM_H

#include <string>
#include <forward_list>
#include <list>
#include "GameObject.h"

using std::string;

/**
 * Represents a room (accessible location in the game).
 */
class Room {
public:
    /**
     * Constructs a new Room.
     * @param _name Name of the room.
     * @param _desc Description of the room.
     */
    Room(const string *_name, const string *_desc);

    /**
     * List storing all rooms that have been registered via addRoom().
     */
    static std::list<Room*> rooms;

    /**
     * Creates a new Room with the given parameters and register it with the static list.
     * @param _name Name of the room.
     * @param _desc Description of the room.
     */
    static Room* addRoom(const string* _name, const string* _desc);
};

#endif //TEXTADV_ROOM_H
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [example]

Comment: "trying to initialize a State object" -- no, the shown code does not initialize anything. It assigned something to an existing object named `currentState`. Can you show how this object is constructed, and prove that it's calling the constructor properly?

Comment: @samVarshavchik Sorry, I confused my terminology. I have updated the question with the initialization of the currentState object. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a repo where we can check this out?
Thanks!

Comment: @LarryDaVinci I've quickly created one you can have a look at: https://github.com/Sterlehelanthropus/c-text-game/tree/main This contains all the important files. There are some references to string (e.g. &r4name) and wordwrap functions. I have not included these files as one is just a file that stores strings and the other is a set of functions for outputting text to the console, which are not related to the issue I am having. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`std::list::front()` returns an iterator. Not (a copy of) the element.
You also **must** check if the list isn't empty first.

```
void initState() {
  if (not Rooms::rooms.empty()) 
    currentState = new State(Room::rooms.front());
}
```

Furthermore, declaring a constructor for your class deletes the default constructor.
You can add it back with `= default`

```cpp
// foo.hpp
class foo {
  int *p_, *k_;
public:
  explicit foo(int*, int*);
  foo() = default;
};

// foo.cpp
foo::foo(int *p, int *k) 
  : p_{ p }, k_{ k }
{}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For the purposes of my program, the list is never empty but thank you for the warning. std::list::front() here returns a read/write reference to the data at the first element of the list and is (I think) returning a pointer as declared in the construction of the list in room.h. Also, adding back the default constructor with = default does not change anything. This code all worked before exactly as is so I'm not sure any of these issues are the problem, but I appreciate the advice. I do see the problem with this implementation (not 100% my own). Thank you.